# Sharepoint on-line separate copies of the same doc for each person?

Tags: sharepoint-online

Sharepoint on-line: how to create separate copies of the same doc for each person?
Is it possible to have a document in Sharepoint that can be edited NON-collaboratively. I need for each employee to be able to fill out a copy of doc in Sharepoint and the copy will be visible only to that employee. Is it possible for all those copies to have the same name and be located in the same folder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As for SharePoint Online, you cannot disable co-authoring, there are two options for you.

1. [Require the file to be checked out before editing](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/set-up-a-library-to-require-check-out-of-files-0c73792b-f727-4e19-a1f9-3173899e695b?ui=en-us&rs=en-us&ad=us) In this way, only one user can check out the file and edit it.
2. For the separate copy, just try to save a copy action in all office
   apps:https://support.office.com/en-us/article/save-a-copy-before-editing-to-prevent-changing-the-original-file-8aeabebe-952e-449b-b931-ae2b7568771b

Note: Simply SharePoint does not support files having the same name, and I think that will cause troubles for users to find the copy belongs to him/her. You can always add the user name after the file name as an identifier.

And as you mention "need for each employee to be able to fill out a copy of doc in Sharepoint and the copy will be visible only to that employee."

Would you like to have a check on [MS forms](https://forms.office.com/Pages/DesignPage.aspx)? It is more like the old surveys which seems to fit your requirements better as users need to fill in their own copy.

Comment: Great help. Much appreciated

Comment: @Michael Glad to be help. You can mark the reply as answer if it resolves your question.

Comment: I clicked on the triangle next to your post and marked it as "useful". Is this what you mean by "mark as answer"? I don't see other options.

Comment: never mind, I found "mark as answer"

Answer (score 0):

If you have few documents, you just upload the files manually in the folder but we can't have with same name, you need to append the file name to make it differentiate, and only share the particular file only with the responsible person - that is access handling.

However, if this is your regular repeated work, you can automate this using the Microsoft flow or workflow.

Comment: it's not what I was asking for, but thank you anyway